# reusing validation code for two text boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to invoke the same validation method for two separate text boxes (with their own custom validators pointing to the same method). The reason, is because they are both part number fields and the validation is to check that the part entered actually exists.

As part of the validation process, I need to get the text entered into the field being validated.

I'm trying this...

```
protected void validatePart_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)source;
    TextBox partNo = (TextBox)FindControl(cv.ControlToValidate);

    args.IsValid = Part.Exists(partNo.Text);
```

but get the error on the line with (`PartNo.Text`)

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm wondering what I need to do to set the partNo `TextBox` correctly from the `ControlToValidate` property of the validation source?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you step through this with a debugger or more logging?  I suspect `FindControl` is returning null.  `CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)source;` should throw an exception if that conversion had failed, so you've correctly identified the source type.  Some debug output would tell you if `cv.ControlToValidate` is the value you expect.  Also try posting the code where the `CustomValidator` is initialized and the `ControlToValidate` property is populated.

Comment: Actually might `CustomValidator cv = (CustomValidator)source;` not throw an exception if source is null?  Are you throwing this event or is this a library class throwing the event?  If yourself, then post the code where the event is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void validatePart_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = Part.Exists(args.Value);
}
```

Comment: quite frankly, what on earth was I thinking? still on that learning curve, thanks for the answer!! :)